# why my guildMemberAdd dont work? anyone can help me?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

For some reason my code doesn't work, can someone help me solve the problem. I've tried everything but I can't solve it.

I'm a beginner.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
    
    let guild = client.guilds.cache.get("856315771131265045");
    let channel = client.channels.cache.get("856338841891635231")
    let emoji = member.guild.cache.find(emoji.name === 'tenor');

    if(guild != member.guild){
        return console.log('Erro (Servidor Errado)')
    } else {

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        .setAuthor(member.user.tag, member.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTitle(`Bem Vindo`)
        .setImage('hhttps://imgur.com/NE1Jx0e')
        .setDescription(`${member.user}, bem vindo ao servidor ${guild.name}! Atualmente temos ${guild.memberCount} membros.`)
        .addField('Canais','Verfica aqui <#856315772770451509>')
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, format: "png", size: 1024}))
        .setFooter('ID: ' + member.user.id)
        .setTimestamp();

        await channel.send(embed)
    }


})
```

Comment: Try logging something inside the event to confirm it's emitting

Answer (score 0):

be sure this parts are open: discord-devoloper--portal > aplications > [your bot] > bot > under of ***Privileged Gateway Intents*** **PRESENCE INTENT*** and ***SERVER MEMBERS INTENT***